# Linking to another page (via URL Hashtag), then Scroll to Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a home page menu bar, that has a "features" anchor link. My features section is actually ont he same page. So when a user clicks the "features" link I have a jQuery function that scrolls them down to that portion of the page. That works as it should.

My problem is, if I'm on another separate page (say /contact-us) that is using the same menu bar, if I click "features" obviously nothing is going to happen. So I wrote this code. Which looks for the URL `http://website.com/#features', then should scroll to that DIV - which it does briefly. Problem is, once the page is FULLY loaded, the page goes back to the top.

What am I doing wrong? Let em know if the above doesn't make sense.

Here's my menu bar anchor:

```
<a href="/#features">FEATURES</a></span>
```

Here's my jQuery snippet that's on the home page:

```
home: function () {
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('#features') > 0) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($('section.feature-set').eq(1).offset().top - 60)
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

****EDIT****

So it wasn't my js code, it was this block of js. This hides iphone safari bar. Seems to be scrolling my page to the top on load. How can I prevent the conflict? I.e. run this block on iPhone only, but also not conflict with my hashtag URL

```
// Hides Safari Address Bar on iPhone
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Did you put your code in $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); ?

Comment: Yes, `$(function (){ });`

Comment: Just figured out what it was...see my edit to my post. new problem...

Comment: What browser are you using? Is it on all of them?

Comment: Chrome...havent checked others. But I found the culprit.

Comment: Is editing the iPhone-specific function a viable option?

Comment: Side Note: you should be using `window.location.hash` if you only care solely about that portion (instead of using an `indexOf` off the whole location).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that code is coming from a library like jQuery mobile? Either way you can modify it to only work when there's not already a direction coming from the URL:

```
if (window.location.hash.length == 0){
  // Hides Safari Address Bar on iPhone
  window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
      // Hide the address bar!
      window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
  });
}
```

Then it will only perform the scroll if a hash tag hasn't been supplied.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume there is already jQuery library is loaded in your page, here you can change interval of scroll. It is working for me.

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(e){

    // Remove the # from the hash
    var loadTarget = location.hash.replace('#','');

    if(loadTarget != ''){

        var $loadTarget = jQuery('#' + loadTarget);
        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $loadTarget.offset().top
            }, 1000, 'swing', function() {

            window.location.hash = '#' + loadTarget;
        });

    }
});
```